# How to get the method declared in specific parent class?

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose the following. There is some superclass or interface declaring some method: `Base.doSmth()`. There is also some inherited class implementing this method: `Inherited.doSmth()`. We have reflection (`Method`) of the `Inherited.doSmth()` and we know what is the base class so that we can access its reflection (`Base.class`). The question is: how to get the reflection on `Base.doSmth()` method? Of course, we can iterate through all methods of `Base` and find one by name, parameters and return types, but maybe there is some solution already. Everything happens in Spring-related class, so code is already coupled to Spring, thus using its utilities is ok.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `public native Class<? super T> getSuperclass();` for access to super class meta data and then using `public Method[] getMethods() throws SecurityException` for access to its methods meta data.

Comment: This is OK, of course, but I think there can be some Spring util-method which makes this work, like `org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.getMostSpecificMethod()`.

Comment: oh,Spring don't have any utility method(may I don't know) but Apache Commons Lang3 have a utility class with ClassUtils name and this class has method with getAllSuperclasses, and other useful methods, may be it class useful for you.

Comment: Thanks MJM, I'll investigate Apache Commons Lang, otherwise make in manually iterating `Method[]` array.